# Camunda: architecture and decisions for a high-performance, dynamic multi tenant app

Tags: multi-tenant, camunda

I'm in charge of building a complex system for my company, and after some research decided that Camunda fits most of my requirements. But some of my requirements are not common, and after reading the user guide I realized there are many ways of doing the same thing, so I hope this question will clarify my thoughts and also will serve as a base questión for everyone else looking for building something similar.

First of all, I'm planning to build a specific App on top of Camunda BPM. It will use workflow and BPM,  but not necessarily all the stuff BPM/Camunda provides. This means it is not in my plans to use mostly of the web apps that came bundled with Camunda (tasks, modeler...), at least not for end users. And to make things more complicated it must support multiple tenants... dynamically.

So, I will try to specify all of my requirements and then hopefully someone with more experience than me could explain which is the best architecture/solution to make this work.

Here we go:

- Single App built on top of Camunda BPM
- High-performance
- Workload (10k new process instances/day after few months).
- Users (starting with 1k, expected to be ~ 50k).
- Multiple tenants (starting with 10, expected to be ~ 1k)
- Tenants dynamically managed (creation, deploy of process definitions)
- It will be deployed on cluster
- PostgreSQL
- WildFly 8.1 preferably

After some research, this are my thoughts

- One Process Application
- One Process Engine per tenant
- Multi tenancy data isolation: schema or table level.
- Clustering (2 nodes) at first for high availability, and adding more nodes when amount of tenants and workload start to rise.

Doubts

- Should I let camunda manage my users/groups, or better manage this on my app? In this case, can I say to Camunda “User X completed Task Y”, even if camunda does not know about the existence of user X?
- What about dynamic multi tenancy? Is it possible to create tenants on the fly and make those tenants persist over time even after restarting the application server? What about re-deployment of processes after restarting?
- After which point should I think on partitioning of engines on nodes? It’s hard to figure out how I’m going to do this with dynamic multi tenancy, but moreover... Is this the right way to deal with high workload and growing number of tenants?
- With my setup of just one process application, should I take care of something else  in a cluster environment?

I'm not ruling out using only one tenant, one process engine and handle everything related to tenants logically within my app, but I understand that this can be very (VERY!) cumbersome.

All answers are welcome, hopefully we'll achieve a good approach to this problem.

Comment: I think this fits better in the forum than in SO, since I cannot see what the accepted answer could be ... it's more like a good discussion starter ...

Comment: See forum post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/camunda-bpm-users/ivKu-enuUXE

Comment: Over the period of time, History processing is being bottleneck in performance so
Keep history level as zero if you are not going to use Camunda Cockpit.
Otherwise I would recommend to configure auto history clean up. there is document available on Camunda website to set auto removal of history/

Answer (score 2):

*1. Should I let camunda manage my users/groups, or better manage this on my app? In this case, can I say to Camunda “User X completed Task Y”, even if camunda does not know about the existence of user X?*

Yes, you can choose your app to manage the users and tell Camunda that a task is completed by a user whom Camunda doesn't know about. And same way, you can make Camunda to assign task to users which it doesn't know at all. This is done by implementing their **org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.identity.ReadOnlyIdentityProvider** interface and let the configuration know about your implementation.

PS: If you doesn't need all the application that comes with Camunda, I would even suggest you to embed the Camunda engine in your app. It can be done easily and they have good documentation for thier java APIs. And it is easily achievable.

*2. What about dynamic multi tenancy? Is it possible to create tenants on the fly and make those tenants persist over time even after restarting the application server? What about re-deployment of processes after restarting?*

Yes. Its possible to dynamically add Tenants. While restarting the engine or your application, you can either choose to redeploy / or just use the existing deployed processes. Even when you redeploy a process, if you want Camunda to create a new version of the  process only if there is a change in the process, that's also possible. See  **enableDuplicateFiltering** property for their **DeploymentBuilder**.

*3. After which point should I think on partitioning of engines on nodes? It’s hard to figure out how I’m going to do this with dynamic multi tenancy, but moreover... Is this the right way to deal with high workload and growing number of tenants?*

In my experience, it is possible. You need to keep track of various parameters here, like memory, number of requests being served, number of open connections available etc., then accordingly add more or remove  nodes. With AWS, this will be much easier as they have some of these tools already available for dynamic scaling in / out nodes. But that said, I have done this only with Camunda as embedded engine application(s).